# Sum of pairwise products divisible by $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

We write three rows of numbers on top of each other, each row consisting of a permutation of $1,2,\dots,n$. It turns out that for each column, the sum of the three pairwise products is divisible by $n$. For which $n$ is this possible?

$n=1$ is obviously possible, and $n=3$ is possible if all rows are $123$. On the other hand, $n=2$ is impossible by trial and error. Taking all rows to be $12\dots n$ doesn't work for any $n>3$.

As written in the comments, for odd $n$ it is possible to have two rows of $1,2,\dots,n$ and one row of $(n-1)/2,n-1,(n-3)/2,n-2,\dots,1,(n+1)/2,n$. Note that if a column consists of two $x$'s and one $y$, the sum of the pairwise products is $x^2+2xy=x(x+2y)$. It then suffices to note that for each column, $x+2y$ is divisible by $n$.

Comment: This is a rather contrived problem.  Where did it come from?

Comment: It is from the Saint Petersburg math competition.

Comment: Is that an ongoing competition?

Comment: Nope, it is from the 2016-17 competition.

Comment: The answer I posted (and deleted) was based on a misreading, but I still suspect it's possible for any odd number...

Comment: Hmm.... $4,8,3,7,2,6,1,5,9$?

Comment: $(n-1)/2,n-1,(n-3)/2,n-2,\ldots,1,(n+1)/2,n$?

Comment: Agreed, that pattern seems to work.

Comment: ...but is it impossible for any even number? That seems to be the harder part, because we actually have to account for all possible permutations in row $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even $n$ is impossible:

Consider each column $a,b,c$.  If all three are odd, then $ab+ac+bc$ is odd.  If two of $a,b,c$ are odd, (say $a=2k$), then $2kb+2kc+bc$ is again odd.

Hence, if $n$ is even, then every column must contain at least two even numbers.  But then we must write at least $\frac{2}{3}(3n)=2n$ even numbers.  This is impossible, since there are only $\frac{n}{2}$ even numbers in each row, so $\frac{3}{2}n$ even numbers total.

---

Odd $n$ is possible:

Let the first two rows be $1,2,\ldots, n$.  Specify the third row (below $a,a$) to be that  $b$ which satisfies $2b+a\equiv 0\pmod{n}$.  This has a unique solution for each odd $n$.  Further, if $2b+a\equiv 0\equiv 2b+a'$, then $a=a'$, so the entries in the third row are indeed a permutation of $1,2,\ldots, n$.

Comment: Contrived, but cute.

Comment: Bravo, well done :)